# Access kubernetes cluster API from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I have a client side react app that was scaffolded out of Create React App. This is deployed in Kubernetes cluster and is exposed to internet.

Now, I would like to access REST API from this API. This REST API is deployed to the same cluster but exposed only to the cluster (not internet).

My question is
If I add Nodejs server layer for my client side react app and deploy to the same cluster, will I be able to access the REST API without being exposed to internet?

Or, should I go with exposing REST API to internet?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow exactly.  However you can access the k8s API from a node.js server deployed in a POD, it will get the same permissions as the POD.

I have something similar to this, an express application running in the pod that provides a REST API for a REACT app, calling the REST API looks up the specific k8s API I need for the APP.  We routinely prototype these REST -> k8sAPIs with NodeRed as well.

Hope this helps, an example below. (full disclosure, hacker not programmer ;-)

example....

```
const axios = require("axios");
const k8s = require("@kubernetes/client-node");


const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();


async function getnskey(user) {
//Match username from gitlab with ns-map/namespace key and return   
    const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

    const response = await k8sApi.readNamespacedConfigMap('ns-map', 'epicmgrsrv')

    let userns;
    
    let userlist = response.body.data;

    if ( userlist.hasOwnProperty(user)) {
        userns = userlist[user];
    }

    const response2 = await k8sApi.readNamespacedSecret('mgrsrvkey', userns)

    //let key = Buffer.from(response2.body.data["key"], 'base64').toString();

    const nskey = {
        userns: userns,
        nskey: response2.body.data["key"],
    };

    return nskey;
}

app.get("/user", (req, res) => {
    console.log("getting user data!");
//    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));


    if (typeof(req.headers.authorization) !== undefined && req.headers.authorization.length > 10 ) {
        axios.get("https://api.github.com/user" , {
            headers: {
                Authorization: req.headers.authorization,
            },
        }).then((response) => {
            getnskey(response.data.login)
            .then(nskey => {

                const user = {
                    name: response.data.login,
                    userns: nskey.userns,
                    nskey: nskey.nskey,
                }
                console.log(user);
                res.send(user)
            })
        });
    } else {
        console.log("no authorization");
    }


    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @oz_adam. So, your react app calls "/user" and it internally calls the REST API "https://api.github.com/user" on the same pod. So, in your case, are the client react app, node.js server, actual REST API  deployed to same cluster or same pod?  Also, if they are deployed to different pods within the same cluster, can they access each other?

If "react app and node.js server" are exposed to internet but not the "REST API",  will it still work?

Pardon me for all these questions. I am a new to Kubernetes and still trying to understand.

Comment: In this app, the frontend react is served by the same express server providing the API shown in the example.  Its providing context for the UI and also setting up calls to another user specific backend.  All of these are behind an API Gateway (ingress or gateway) which connects them to the internet.  The API gateway is used to direct the subsequent user specific requests based upon routing rules in the gateway.  You will probably also notice OAUTH calls in the code, this is something that we will move to the Gateway in the future to make this backend and the other backends simpler.

Comment: A common pattern is API Gateway(ingress)-backend-backenddb where both the Backend and its database or other system are in the same cluster, the backend communicates with its backenddb in other PODs, communicating within the cluster, we are not doing that in this case.

Comment: Thank you, @oz_adam. We ended up in having ngnix serving the client side react app and as well as use it as reverse proxy for accessing backend endpoints. Ngnix server and backend services are deployed to the same cluster.